# How to get NLP synonyms

Tags: python-2.7, nlp, nltk, wordnet

I have this snippet for getting synonyms (I got it from one of the posts). I want to get the synonyms in a list and not as it prints as shown below

```
from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn
import nltk
from nltk.corpus.reader.plaintext import PlaintextCorpusReader

def me():
    T = []
    for i,j in enumerate(wn.synsets('small')):
        #print "Synonyms:", ", ".join(j.lemma_names())
        for item in [", ".join(j.lemma_names())]:
            print T.append(item)
```

If I use : 
`print item`, 
I get this answer:

```
small
small
small, little
minor, modest, small, small-scale, pocket-size, pocket-sized
little, small
small
humble, low, lowly, modest, small
little, minuscule, small
little, small
small
modest, small
belittled, diminished, small
small
```

If I use 
    `print T.append(item)`,
I get this:

```
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
None
```

what I want is this:

```
[ small, little, minor, modest, small-scale, pocket-size, pocket-sized, humble, low, lowly, minuscule, belittled, diminished]
```

Answer (score 2):

`T.append(item)` appends `item` to the list and returns `None`. if i understand correctly, you want to see the list growing (right?). then you could try this:

```
for item in [", ".join(j.lemma_names())]:
    T.append(item)
    print T
```

or (maybe better); `return T` at the end of your method and use it like this:

```
T = me()
print T
```